# Ember.js gives infinte loop when using {{#each}} tag in template

Tags: arrays, ember.js, handlebars.js

Using Ember.js I get an endless loop with the following code:

Controller:

```
App.activityDetailsController = Em.Object.create({
  activityBinding :     'App.navController.selectedActivity',

  data : function(){
    var things = new Array();
    if(this.activity){
      var info = this.activity.get('info');
      var len = info.length;
      for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        for(prop in info[i]){
          things.push({"key": prop, "value" : info[i][prop]});       
        }
      }
    }

    return things;
  }.property('activity')    
})
```

View:

```
App.ActivityDetailsView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName :        'activity-details',
  activityBinding :     'App.activityDetailsController.activity',
  dataBinding :         'App.activityDetailsController.data'

})
```

Template:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="activity-details">
    <div id="info">
      {{#each data}}
          {{key}}: {{value}}<br />
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </script>
```

When trying to load this page, the 'data' function in the controller is called endlessly.

If I remove the {{#each}}{{/each}} block from the view, there is no problem and using {{data.length}} in the template gives the correct output.

Any ideas why this loops endlessly?  If I remove 'activity' from the property call, it the problem is the same.

Thanks,

Comment: Wait, won't #each data return a function, not the value of that function? If you want to return a value, why not make it a computer property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your "data" property `cacheable()`.  See [ebryn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873281/1204216) to a related question for the reason why.